# Export from Xcode and import into Eclipse

Tags: xcode, eclipse, import, export

I'm working on a project for school in C and i use Xcode, all my other classmates are using Eclipse with the C/C++ perspective so, is there any way that I could export my Xcode project and import it on another PC with eclipse ?

Comment: I dont know how to to that but I highly recommend continue using Xcode. My opinion is that its much faster, less buggy and overall has a better user experience.
But thats just my opinion. You should decide what IDE you want to use

Comment: The problem is not what I will use, the problem is what my colleagues use, we have to exchange projects and they all work on eclipse so it is kinda hard for me to switch projects with one of them ... but I totally agree with you, that Xcode is way better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set up a new project in Eclipse and import your files into the new project. Maybe you will have to recreate your individual structure with folders ect but I think you wont be able to get that from the xcode-projectfile anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation, and I just compress the Project file in my workspace and it becomes a zip that my TA usually is able to run.